# The method Save isn't defined for the class State ? || Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

**Do you help solve this problem ?**
*I have a problem save()*

[image]

> The method 'save' can't be unconditionally invoked because the
> receiver can be 'null'.

```
TextFormField(
  onSaved:(val){
    _authData['email'] = val.toString() ;
    print( _authData['email']);
  } ,

),
 ElevatedButton(onPressed: _submit, child: Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login? 'Login' : 'Signup')),
//-------------------

void _submit() {
_formKey.currentState.save();

}
```

Comment: Is that... _Comic Sans_?

Comment: Anyway, please tell us if you understand the error message or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change below line ,add null check operator(!) refer `null-safety` [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

```
_formKey.currentState.save();
```

To

```
_formKey.currentState!.save();
```

Or

```
_formKey.currentState?.save();
```

Comment: **I tried? ! But it didn't work**    `_formKey.currentState?.save();`  - The method 'save' isn't defined for the type 'State'.

Comment: are you try `_formKey.currentState!.save();`, can you tell me how to declare _formKey?

Comment: Thank you you alerted me I had a problem with the key
was before
`GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey();`
and modified it for `final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
`

Comment: yes `final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();` its correct way or this also `final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();` if your problem is solved by my answer accept and upvote it,Thanks@Mohammadalqannas

Answer (score 1):

```
 formKey.currentState?.save()
```

Add null check for state before calling save method

Comment: **I tried? ! But it didn't work**    `_formKey.currentState?.save();`  - The method 'save' isn't defined for the type 'State'.

Answer (score 0):

**There was a problem with the key**

> was before

```
GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey();
```

And that's wrong X

> And the correct one is ✔✔

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
```